# Comparing mathematical expressions

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, math, floating-point

So here's my situation: I have two mathematical expressions which contains variables (x, y, z, etc). I have already compiled them to postfix using the [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) for execution and now I need a way to test if they're mathematical equal.

Examples:

```
x+5==5+x
x*2==x+x
4/(x/2)==8/x
```

My initial thinking is to just throw a couple of thousand different random inputs and see if the evaluation result is the same.

Problems I foresee with this approach: Precision problems, NaN-situations and possible overflows.

All calculations are done with Java's double type.

Any ideas? :)

Edit: As this is for a casual game, the solution doesn't need to be perfect, only good enough!

Comment: possible duplicate http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55579/numerical-solution-for-a-system-of-multivariate-polynomial-equations

Comment: The logical theory of real numbers is decidable, so it is possible to solve it "correctly".

Answer (score 5):

For the example expressions you have provided, you could transform the function to produce one polynomial divided by another, with the most significant coefficient of the divisor one, and with no common factor. This would give you a canonical form - if there was a difference the two functions would really be different. However, you would also need to represent the coefficients as arbitrary precision rationals or hit precision problems here too, and by then you will have written most of a basic computer algebra system, such as those listed at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems - which does include some free systems.

Comment: Seems a bit overkill for my rather simple needs :)

Comment: For a game, I guess you could change the rules so that equal +/- 0.1% for a few thousand random numbers counted as equality - or look to see if it is easy to plug in one of the free algebra packages.          Think _you_ are hard done by? my simple need is to do the same thing in polynomial time with multivariate boolean expressions :-)

Answer (score 4):

According to Wikipidea on this topic:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation

"There are two notions of equality for mathematical expressions. The syntactic equality is the equality of the expressions which means that they are written (or represented in a computer) in the same way. As trivial, it is rarely considered by mathematicians, but it is the only equality that is easy to test with a program. The semantic equality is when two expressions represent the same mathematical object, like in

It is known that there may not exist a algorithm that decides if two expressions representing numbers are semantically equal, if exponentials and logarithms are allowed in the expressions. Therefore (semantical) equality may be tested only on some classes of expressions such as the polynomials and the rational fractions.

To test the equality of two expressions, instead to design a specific algorithm, it is usual to put them in some canonical form or to put their difference in a normal form and to test the syntactic equality of the result."

That seems to be the best practice.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to write basically the same question when I ended up here. However I found some ideas which are not mentionned here.
First, I agree with @nelshh that in some specific cases you can find canonical forms which allow to test equality of expressions.

I found some examples of canonical forms:

- The most famous is probably the [minterm canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form) in the boolean algebra which is used for instance in circuit synthesis or verification.
- Polynomial expressions also admit a canonical form as a sum of monomials. This can solve your examples:
- The canonical form for rational numbers is the [irreductible fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_fraction).

Your examples:

1. Both are already in canonical form, you just need to sort them by increasing degree.
2. `2*x` is in its canonical form, `x+x` is not (because both operands of the addition have same degree).
3. Both are already in canonical form (monomials of degree -1), except that the coefficient in `4/(x/2)` which is `4/(1/2)` is not in the canonical forms for rational numbers.

If you are still interested in this, I would suggest that you experiment with a computer algebra system such as sympy for python (it probably also exists for java). However, I also think that you should remove the tags `java` and `floating-point` (it has nothing to do with how a computer stores real numbers), and add the tag `computer-science`.

For instance sympy is able to tell such things:

```
>>> Rational(3,4)*(x+y)**2
         2
3⋅(x + y) 
──────────
    4     
>>> Rational(3,4)*(x**2+y**2)+Rational(1,4)*2*x*y+Rational(4,8)*2*x*y
   2              2
3⋅x    3⋅x⋅y   3⋅y 
──── + ───── + ────
 4       2      4  
>>> expand(Rational(3,4)*(x+y)**2)==expand(Rational(3,4)*(x**2+y**2)+Rational(1,4)*2*x*y+Rational(4,8)*2*x*y)
True
```